# Excel VBA code: Having troubles opening new workbook, copying range to original workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning-

I've managed to piece together a code that will, from my original workbook, open a new workbook, copy a specific range and paste that range back to the original workbook and close the referenced workbook.  I've tested each section of my code, and it seems to work perfectly until I run the entire code together.

Now I continuously get a

> 'subscript out of range'

error, that no matter what I try to modify, will not go away.  I've researched as much as I can to try to figure out the differences.

As always, thank you to the StackOverflow users that help me always workout my issues!

```
Sub import()
  Dim x As Workbook
  Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
  Set y = ThisWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    End With
  Set x = ActiveWorkbook

'##Now, copy what you want from x:
  x.Sheets("QBEPaymentAdvice").Range("D13", "T60").Copy


'##Now, paste to y worksheet:
  y.Sheets("QBE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'##Close Workbook x
  x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, your use of `FileDialog` does nothing. It shows the files, but does nothing to determine which file  was selected by the user and use it. (IOW, it's like a magic trick where the magician says *Pick a card, but don't let me see it. Ok, the trick is over..*) It serves no purpose. I'd start by fixing that first, and then  go on from there.

Comment: I recommend to use descriptive variable names to avoid errors and for better maintenance. Eg. instead of `x` and `y` use `SourceWs` and `DestWs` which is much more descriptive and easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: @KenWhite - That makes perfect sense of why I get the out of range.  If it only shows the file, then of course it doesn't have the appropriate range to be able to copy.  Thank you!

Pᴇʜ Agreed.  I was trying to use something simple with less keystrokes, but it does make it extremely confusing later.  

Thank you both for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way :

```
Sub import()
  Dim x As Workbook
  Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
  Set y = ThisWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

                If .Show Then
           xlFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
           'if user pressed CANCEL - exit sub
           MsgBox "User pressed CANCEL"
           Exit Sub
        End If


    End With
  Set x = Workbooks.Open(xlFileName)

'##Now, copy what you want from x:
  x.Sheets("QBEPaymentAdvice").Range("D13", "T60").Copy


'##Now, paste to y worksheet:
  y.Sheets("QBE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'##Close Workbook x
  x.Close

End Sub
```